# What exactly is a guild mark?

Tags: fairy-tail

All guild members have a mark of their guild, what exactly are they? Is it just a regular tattoo or is there some kind of magic contract?

[image]

Comment: I'd go for a magic contract since, when the tatoo disappears, it becomes some kind of magic dust

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guild Mark is a kind of magic contract which is printed magically on each guild member. It helps in identifying a mage's guild.

Sometimes it can be used to perform group magic, for e.g., during the Tenrou Island Arc the members of Fairy Tail combined their power against Acnologia to defend against its attack.

Also, during the Grand Magic Tournament Mavis says only those having the Fairy Tail guild mark are able to see her.

Comment: thanks for the edit. guess still unable to form sentences properly. English isn't my first language.

Comment: debal: u seem to know a lot about anime so i was wondering if you could tell me whether fairy tail is as good as one piece, naruto or bleach?

Comment: all I can say is I like each of the mangas you mentioned along with Fairy Tail. If you look at the popularity of these manga, you will see they are all very popular, so a large audience must feel that they are good. Apart from that its completely your taste. :)

Comment: well, if the main character is an underdog who develops over time then I'm definitely gonna like it.

Comment: but be prepared for some hardcore nakama power and plenty of fan service. mashima is the only artist to not compromise on these two points.