# Is it possible to have 2 guild marks?

Tags: fairy-tail

The [What exactly is a guild mark?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/8308/what-exactly-is-a-guild-mark) question made me wonder about allot of things regarding the guild mark.

One of the things would be: Is it possible to have multiple guild marks from either the same, or even other guilds? Or has it been stated that this is not possible somewhere?

Comment: i don't remember any mention of it in the manga.

Comment: maybe possible. can't tell for sure but evan and hades did have guild mark before forming their own.

Comment: @Sp0T didn't Hades and Evan got out from Fairy Tail before they make their own guild?

Comment: I don't think it would be possible to have two. They would probably have to have it removed first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether it's possible or not is currently unknown. It has not been revealed in the manga or the anime yet however other guilds will not let any wizard have 2 guild marks at the same time. This will question their devotion to the guild and it will be meaningless to stay in either of them. A guild is a family and you can only have one family.

It is arguable that the guild marks can be hidden under their clothes and nobody would notice. However some guild marks, like Fairy Tail's, is more than just a mark, it is a magic contract too as stated in the link you have given. It has not been shown that other guilds have them but it is possible to corrupt a wizard's magic with 2 different magic contract on their body. Just imagine 2 different natures of magic going on in a wizard's body.

Comment: Just saying but the Guild Sabertooth definitely didn't consider everyone as one big family. They were the quite opposite.